# Thunderbird displays IMAP folders incorrectly (gmail account)

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I have set up Icedove (Thunderbird) to use my gmail account with IMAP. I would like to have my IMAP folder structure

```
gmail.com
    - Inbox
    - Drafts
    - Sent
    - Trash
```

However, the actual folder structure loos like this:

[image]

With Inbox being displayed correctly, but the rest of the folders nested inside subfolder "gmail".

**Is it possible to fix this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that thunderbird displays it incorrectly.

> Gmail uses a special implementation of IMAP. In this implementation, Gmail labels become Thunderbird folders. When you apply a label to a message in Gmail, Thunderbird creates a folder with the same name as the label and stores the message in that folder. Similarly, if you move a message to a folder in Thunderbird, Gmail will create a label with the folder name and assign it to the message.

You can read more [here](https://support.mozilla.org/bg/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail#w_understanding-gmail-labels-and-thunderbird-folders).
To achieve order you want there is useful extension [Flat Folder Tree](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/thunderbird/addon/flat-folder-tree/).

Comment: `Flat Folder Tree` solved the problem. Thanks.